# In textile, how do I set the class of an (un)ordered list?

Tags: textile

Using textile, I can set the class of a table by writing

```
table(myClass).
| a | b | c |
```

produces

```html
<table class="myClass">
...
```

But how can I do the same thing for (un)ordered lists?

```
# Item 1
# Item 2
# Item 3
```

to make textile product

```html
<ol class="myClass">
  <li>...
```

Comment: I am unaware on how to achieve it for the enclosing element, but it may be of help to know that one can add classes to the **li** elements themselves using this syntax: `#(my-class) Item`